# svg image position in browser

Tags: html, css, image, svg

I'm trying to get an SVG image to at the top left of a web page after the text. Not sure what the problem is, appreciate any help.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>test SVG</title>
    </head>
<body>
    This is the top of the screen
      <br />
<object type="image/svg+xml"
        width="612px" height="792px" viewBox="0 0 612 792"
        preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"
        data="http://www.chordsandguitar.com/forms/forms-minor11.svg"
        <!-- your browswer cannot display this image -->
</object>
```

the link is: http://www.chordsandguitar.com/forms/test.htm

Seems like no matter what I do the browser (Firefox) does not respond, I tried width and height = 100% preserveaspectratio ="none", no difference in the appearance of the image.

Thanks

Comment: The `viewBox` and `preserveAspectRatio` attributes must be in the svg document, they have no effect when put on the <object> element.

Comment: Your SVG image is actually at the top left. Set background color to object and see.

Comment: There is extra space because SVG objects lowest `y` is `300+px`

Answer (score 2):

OK, my problem had nothing to do with the svg attributes, it had to do with how the svg file was created. I am using adobe illustrator CS4, the image in Illustrator has to be positioned top left corner of the illustrator canvas to get the result I expect. Maybe I can translate the image using the svg attributes but there's no point.

By the way here is a great explanation of how viewport/viewbox works:

http://sarasoueidan.com/blog/svg-coordinate-systems/